# How to get share function to work with gapi

Tags: google-drive-api, share, google-api-js-client

I get error using gapi´s share function.

**Open Url in drive_sdk:**

> http://docswriter.com/#/edit/{ids}

**The page is also verified in googles search console as:**

> docswriter.com

**Share function in js:**

```
factory.share = function(fileid) {
        var appid = '***********'; //Using App ID from Drive UI Integration
        var init = function() {
            var s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient(appid);
            s.setItemIds([fileid]);
            s.showSettingsDialog();
        }
        gapi.load('drive-share', init);
    };
```

**Error:**

> Refused to display
>   'https://drive.google.com/sharing/share?id=10RAw2XV2n3qizC237Z_HoXcbeeWeuEDS…ient=postMessage&appId=***********&embedOrigin=http%3A%2F%2Fdocswriter.com'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by making a [chrome web store listing](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/listing) with the app id inside the manifest file like this: (app id as api_console_project_id)

```
{
  "name": "Docswriter",
  "description": "App to write documentation",
  "version": "0.0.0.2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "api_console_project_id" : "4********3",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "http://docswriter.com/"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://docswriter.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

When I then installed the app from chrome web store, it worked.